# HTML/Electron: Prevent dropping draggable data outside of application

Tags: javascript, html, electron, draggable

I am making an electron application where a user uses the [html drag and drop api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) to transfer data between windows. For example a user might click and drag a tab setting dataTransfer to hold a JSON object with information about itself. A user would then drop that tab onto a tabpane in another window and the information would be moved.

However I am having an issue where a user can drag the tab into another application, say the search bar of Google Chrome or any other input that accepts plain text where it will paste the JSON. I would like to stop the application from dropping information unless it is on the tabpane in the same application.

```
    $(document).on('dragstart', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(dummyGetTabAsJSON($(this))));
        ...
    });

    // Allow tabs as drop targets
    $(document).on('dragover', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('drop', '.tabpane li', function(e) {
        // TODO: Prevent dropping of tab JSON into other applications or inputs
        var data = dummyCreateTabFromJSON(JSON.parse(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')));
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types):

"**Dragging Custom Data**

You can also use other types that you make up for custom purposes. You should strive to always include a plain text alternative unless that object being dragged is specific to a particular site or application. In this case, the custom type ensures that the data cannot be dropped elsewhere."

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('customtext', JSON.stringify(dummyGetTabAsJSON($(this))));
...
var data = dummyCreateTabFromJSON(JSON.parse(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('customtext')));
```